# Subtracting Hours and Minutes from DateTime not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datetime

I am trying to subtract hours and minutes from a DateTime variable and I have found other posts that show that you should be able to use the .AddHours(-3) in order to achieve this but it is not working for me. I am grabbing the datetime from a DateTimePicker control in vb.net. say the time is 10:00 AM, I want to subtract 3 hours from this to make it 7:00 AM. My hours variable evaluates to -3 but even when I just literally put the number -3 inside the .AddHours it still does not subtract the time. Heres the code

```
Dim ApptTime As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Value)
        Dim travelTime As String = Label60.Text
        Dim newtime As Double
        Dim split() As String = travelTime.Split(" ")
        If split.Length = 2 Then
            Dim Minutes As String = split(0).Replace("mins", "")
        Else
            Dim Hours As Double = split(0).Replace("Hours", "")
            Dim Minutes As Double = split(2).Replace("mins", "")
            Hours = -Hours
            Minutes = -Minutes
            ApptTime.AddHours(Hours)
            ApptTime.AddMinutes(Minutes)
            Label62.Text = (ApptTime.ToString)
```

Comment: they are functions returning the new values: `AppTime = ApptTime.AddHours(Hours)`

Comment: Something so simple... Ha Thanks for your help, that did the trick

Comment: It always helps to read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "This method does not change the value of this `DateTime`. Instead, it returns a new `DateTime` whose value is the result of this operation..."

Comment: this is not needed either: `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker2.Value)`  the DTP.Value **is already** a DateTime Type

Comment: Ok, I believe I had the conversion because I started out trying to use the `DateTimePicker2.text` instead of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple error ...

```
Dim ApptTime As DateTime = Now
        'ApptTime.Subtract(New TimeSpan(1, 60, 60)) 'won't work
        ApptTime = ApptTime.Subtract(New TimeSpan(1, 60, 60)) '1h , 60m , 60s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Dim NowMinusThreeHours = DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, -3, Now)
```